# maximum of determinants of matrices with coefficients $0$ or $1$

Tags: combinatorics, matrices, determinant

Let $F(n) $ be the maximum of the determinant over all $n \times n$ matrices with all coefficients being either $0$ or $1$.

**Question**: What is $F(n)$?

My low dimensional computations where $F(1)=1$, $F(2) = 1$, $F(3) = 2$, $F(4) = 3$.

My argument for $n=4$ was already rather complicated and not so elegant. This data would suggest that there is $F(n)=n-1$ for $n>1$, but I have no idea. It would be really cool if there is an elegant way to compute it for all $n$.

Comment: Check out https://oeis.org/A003432

Comment: Thank you very much, if you post the link as answer then I will accept.